# Web portal not working with MS CRM online when connecting internet directly instead of wifi

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I am working on a project where we use MS Dynamics CRM and we also have MVC web portal on top of it.

All is working fine when I connect my laptop with wifi connection instead of direct connection. My guess is that when I connect directly the proxy server not allow my web application to fetch data from CRM online.

I just create a console application and I can fetch data from CRM through wifi and direct connection as well so the issue is only with web application. i.e. It appears that web application with direct internet connection is not working.

Following is the exception when I connect to the direct connection and try to fetch the CRM records.

*Unable to connect to the remote server*

Again all is working fine when I connect with wifi.

Comment: Is the CRM online reachable via browser ?

Comment: yes crm online is reachable via browser, I select automatically select the proxy server under internet option.

Comment: Can you say more about how the console app authenticates with crm online?